Query regarding Iptables rule deleting
When I am deleting an iptable rule for example below rule:
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
It is getting added again as rule number 1. Can someone explain why it is happening like that.
I want to restrict ssh traffic for specific IPs only, for rest of the IPs in my LAN I want to disallow.
